# How to block internet for other users in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, internet

Is there any way to **block** a user to use **Internet in Windows Xp**.

Suppose **user A** is an **Administrator** of windows Xp os & he wants to block **user B** who is just a **Guest**. Then how user a could do that?

Comment: What would you consider Internet use?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's not possible to block access to sockets to set the firewall per-user.

For Windows 7, it appears that a third-party software can be used to [manipulate the Windows Firewall per-user](http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/server.html), but this appears not to apply to Windows XP.

If simply blocking use of a web browser is sufficient, you could set the permissions on iexplore.exe and any other browsers you have to deny access to the Guest account. This would effectively prevent them from using a web browser (assuming you have no others installed). You could also deny access to other internet-based applications.

Just keep in mind that this will not guarantee the user can't access the internet, only inhibit general users. Even a modestly skilled user could bring his thumb drive with his own browser and run it from the guest account.

Answer (score 0):

- You could set user rights in the group policies. See: http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/20796-post10.html
- Alternatively, if your guest doesn't have much technical knowledge, you could make the browser use a non-existing proxy, so it can't connect
- You could also set up a real proxy with authentication that only allows authenticated users to connect to the internet

Answer (score 0):

May be try setting up a transparent proxy on your machine. And don't give out the password to the guest.
http://www.bofi.camelot.de/squid.htm

Answer (score -2):

Set a password and don't give it out.

Comment: The question implies that the user should be able to log in and run applications, but just not use the Internet.

Comment: Completely unhelpful as the question actually implies that the guest is welcome to use the machine but not the internet connection...